# GCF: Pubsub invokes old versions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there any version/source update step or action that needs to be done when building GCFs with Cloudbuild. Or is there anyway to make sure that pubsub topic invokes the latest GCF version?

I've got a bunch of GCFs that are built with CloudBuild, and afterwards invoked by a pubsub topic. Weirdly some of them (not all) throw an error from a previous version of the GCF (the last GCF build actually fixes the error).

GCFs source code shows what's expected: the latest version of the code
Yet, GCF throws error that was in the GCF's previous version source code.
That line doesn't even exist in the source code of the currently active GCF's version (GCF > Functions > FUNC_NAME > Source).

In some occasions it's been a few hours since a GCF deployment and the first invocation.

Comment: possibly relevant note in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying#migrating_between_deployments

Comment: yep, that's similar to what @al-dann posted below, but it's several hours between the deployment till the invocation, so it's got to be a fresh instance, which is supposed to be built on latest version, but it's not

Comment: You have specific issue or you are looking for best practice/how to question? Could you specify what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: It's a specific issue I've got right now. Pubsub invokes old versions of the GCF. If there is something in the setup I've missed that I need to change, I'd love to know that, but this behaviour is quite unexpected and annoying at least

Comment: Could you share detailed steps to replicate this behavior? I'd like to visualize this issue.

Comment: - Set up CloudBuild to create GCF on push to Google Source Repo
=> Pushed to Source Repo to trigger GCF build
=> Tested GCF (printed a text to logs)
=> Removed the text printing from GCF and pushed to SourceRepo to trigger GCF rebuilding
=> Waited for cloud build to finish and tested GCF again 
=> got the same text, although there is no such line in the last version of the GCF source code (checked the source code both in the console and in the cloud source repo

Answer (score 1):

From the best of my understanding, a new code is to be used at a "cold start" of a next "slot/instance" of a cloud function... And if you have some instances being used constantly - when one invocation is finished, the next one uses this (just became available) available "runtime environment slot", so that the environment is not created from scratch. Thus, it may take some time until all those "slots" are substituted with new, which have the new version of code being uploaded when the environment is created.

You might prefer to delete the cloud function, and then recreate it (using the new code), or drain the pubsub, so there is a pause in cloud functions being triggered.

Comment: I thought about it, but there is no way those functions would come from re-used instance, it's been several hours from the build till the invocation.